# After convert my code to swift 3 Twitter not get the users profile image

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap, swift3, fhs-twitter-engine

I'm using `FHSTwitter Engine`. In that, I can get `Username` by using `FHSTwitterEngine.shared().authenticatedUsername` this. But 
`FHSTwitterEngine.shared().getProfileImageURLString(forUsername: username as String, andSize: FHSTwitterEngineImageSizeOriginal` in this I got error like `Error Domain=FHSErrorDomain Code=204 "The request did not return any content.` How to I get profile image? 
But It's work fine for swift 2.0. How to solve this Issue.

Comment: I just checked, the method signature has changed to:
`func getProfileImageURLString(forUsername username: String, andSize size: FHSTwitterEngineImageSize) -> Any {
}`, and the error is definitely there, may an ill formed request. Any chance i can look at the code snippet?

Comment: In my FHSTwitterEngine.m file the function is Like   - (id)getProfileImageURLStringForUsername:(NSString *)username andSize:(FHSTwitterEngineImageSize)size {
    
   
}

Comment: Have you tried, updating your `FHSTwitterEngine `https://github.com/fhsjaagshs/FHSTwitterEngine

Comment: No, I'm not trying yet.

Comment: So that would be the problem, your existing frameworks which were written for Swift 2 can't work on Swift 3. So please change them. Otherwise no use asking question here. Cheers!

Comment: Okay, Sure I will update the frameworks. Cheers.

Comment: Now I update the framework but getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when the user name is incorrect. This should work.

```
let profilepic = FHSTwitterEngine.shared().getProfileImageURLString(forUsername: FHSTwitterEngine.shared().authenticatedUsername, andSize: FHSTwitterEngineImageSizeOriginal)
print("profile pic is \(profilepic)")
```

Comment: Hi Naveen,Thanks for saving me. Your answer working for me.